# not represented in specified output encoding of UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a java program which reads docx files line by line with Apache POI. I have a word list and if I match this word in one line, I print the line from docx file. So far, I had not problem. Today I had an output like this :

**Attempt to output character of integral value 0 that is not represented in specified output encoding of UTF-8.**

What does this mean ? And please provide me a solution.

Thank you.

My code where I read docx file and print the line.

```
URL url = new URL(URL.get(y));

File file = new File("E:\\demo\\myfile.docx");

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);

POITextExtractor extractor1 = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(file);     

String text = extractor1.getText();

StringReader sr = new StringReader(text);

BufferedReader readme = new BufferedReader(sr);             

while ((sCurrentLine3 = readme.readLine()) != null) {

sCurrentLine3= sCurrentLine3.trim().replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll(" ", "");

sCurrentLine3 = "Z:" + sCurrentLine3;

sCurrentLine3 = sCurrentLine3.replace("/", "\\");

System.out.println(ObjectsLine.get(i) + " " + Change.get(y) + " " + sCurrentLine3);
```

Comment: Could you provide us with your code?

Comment: James, I added the part of my code where I read the docx file and print the line. @JamesZafar

Comment: Unfortunately not sufficient information. General advice: split your problem in reading (check), and then writing (check). A read String can be saved with `Files.writeAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/temp.txt"), string.getBytes("UTF-8"));`.